# i want to span columns in mysql result displayed on my page

Tags: php, mysql

hello everyone i have made a mysql table which consist of two columns and 35 rows,
now problem is i want to span or merge some of the columns in it but i don't know how to do it
here is my code

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Spec");
echo "<table border='1' id='spec'>
 <tr>
 <th class='th'>Engine</th>
 <th class='th'>Spec</th>
 </tr>";

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td class='td1'>" . $row['Engine'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td class='td'>" . $row['Spec'] . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
  }
  if($row['Engine'] = $row['Suspension'])
  {
   echo "<td colspan='2'>" . $row['Suspension'] . "</td>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: you have already spanned

Comment: if($row['Engine'] = $row['Suspension']) should be  if($row['Engine'] == $row['Suspension']) but by the way how do you get $row["Suspension"]??? You said you only have 2 columns..

Comment: suspent in singlesion is row under column Engine i want to merge it in single

Comment: you may want to change to mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem with  and  in while loop, please update it accordingly.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
   echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td class='td1'>" . $row['Engine'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='td'>" . $row['Spec'] . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
  }
  if($row['Engine'] = $row['Suspension'])
  {
   echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td colspan='2'>" . $row['Suspension'] . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Several problems with your logic there and a couple of code issues.  Since you haven't explained exactly what format your data is in and what layout you want to achieve I'll have a bash at both versions you can test them and see which one fits the layout you're after.

This version fixes the IF statement to correctly use comparitive operator of == not assignment of = 
It also creates a new table row if the engine and suspension column values match so you'd end up with something looking like this

```
|  ENGINE  |  SPEC  |
|      SUSPENSION   |

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Spec");
echo "<table border='1' id='spec'>
 <tr>
 <th class='th'>Engine</th>
 <th class='th'>Spec</th>
 </tr>";

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td class='td1'>" . $row['Engine'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td class='td'>" . $row['Spec'] . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
      if($row['Engine'] == $row['Suspension']) {
         echo "<tr><td colspan='2'>" . $row['Suspension'] . "</td></tr>";
      }
  }
  echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
```

Of course it relies that the contents of your Suspension column are exactly the same as the contents of your Engine column which I'll place a bet on they don't but you'll have to address you're logic about that

The other way of doing it is like this.  This version will show `| ENGINE | SPEC |` or if your engine column matches your Suspension column it'll just show the `| SUSPENSION |` column instead.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Spec");
    echo "<table border='1' id='spec'>
     <tr>
     <th class='th'>Engine</th>
     <th class='th'>Spec</th>
     </tr>";

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
       if($row['Engine'] == $row['Suspension']) {
           echo "<tr><td colspan='2'>" . $row['Suspension'] . "</td></tr>";
       } else {
           echo "<tr>";
           echo "<td class='td1'>" . $row['Engine'] . "</td>";
           echo "<td class='td'>" . $row['Spec'] . "</td>";
           echo "</tr>";     
       }
      }
      echo "</table>";
    mysqli_close($con);
```

Both will work though I suspect neither will provide you what you're looking for personally I don't think you need the IF() statement at all

Comment: actually its not a column its a type of sub-content under Engine column, under suspension its related data is present like
|Engine|Spec|
|suspension|   |
front---data
rear---Data
as you can see i want to merge that one(suspension and its right one)

Comment: If suspension exists as part of engine column then none of this will work at all anyway.  You need an extra column that contains suspension data and then you can just delete the if statement as its not needed any more.